# C# Multiple Digital Signatures on Documents

Tags: c#, .net, document, digital-signature

I have a requirement in a C# .net application to be able to add multiple digital signatures to a document.  The document will be uploaded as a template then will go through several stages of processing (mail merge) and will then be downloaded.  There is a requirement to have several parties each digitally sign it.

I have the following questions

1) Will each individual will need a seperate cert to sign with.
2) Are my options to install office on the webserver or to purchase 3rd party components.
3) I would greatly appreciate any examples in c#/.net (either with docx or pdf to demonstrate this)

Comment: use adobe EchoSign or DocuSign, both have rich api to integrate with dot net code and support multi party and in a given order signature support

Comment: Thanks for those, I'll investigate. I presume using one of these services will mean my application submitting a document to their api and getting a signed copy back?  If I have many digital signatures is this something I need to configure in advance? e.g. If User1, User2, User3 and User4 are all required to sign a document will each need to be registered seperately with the provider?

Comment: no. just the sender should be registered. not all of them

Answer (score 1):

Below am writing a code using DocuSign WebService to send document to be signed by multiple parties:
you can get the WebService(.asmx) url from their Site and steps on how to add this `Service Reference` to your project.

You can get details on what is Envelope or Tabs from [here](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/api-explorer)

```
Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
envelope.Subject = subject;
envelope.EmailBlurb = "This is Awesome. Kung fu Panda is just awesome";
envelope.AccountId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIAccountId"];

Recipient recipient = new Recipient();
recipient.UserName = name;
recipient.Email = txtRecipientEmail.Text;
recipient.ID = "1";
recipient.Type = RecipientTypeCode.Signer;

//here you can add multiple recipients
envelope.Recipients = new Recipient[] { recipient };


Document document = new Document();
document.PDFBytes =  FileHelper.StreamToByteArray(fileUploadTool1.FileContent );
document.FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileUploadTool1.PostedFile.FileName);
document.Name = Path.GetFileName(fileUploadTool1.PostedFile.FileName);
document.ID = "1";
envelope.Documents = new Document[] { document };

Tab tab1 = new Tab();
tab1.RecipientID = "1";
tab1.PageNumber = "1";
tab1.DocumentID = "1";
tab1.Type = TabTypeCode.SignHere;
tab1.XPosition = "50";
tab1.YPosition = "200";

Tab tab2 = new Tab();
tab2.RecipientID = "1";
tab2.PageNumber = "1";
tab2.DocumentID = "1";
tab2.Type = TabTypeCode.DateSigned;
tab2.XPosition = "110";
tab2.YPosition = "225";

envelope.Tabs = new Tab[] { tab1, tab2 };
APIServiceSoapClient proxy = Get_Proxy();
EnvelopeStatus status = proxy.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
StatusLabel.Text = "The envelope is " + status.Status.ToString() + ".";
```

Comment: Am I right in saying this could get quite expensive. I see mention of $20 a month per user. My application is small portal but would have around 50-60 users all needing to sign documents through my application.  All I would ever use is the API to communicate with my product so I'm not sure how that works with their licensing model.

Comment: There are different prices for apps. You should just ask about transaction pricing rather than seat pricing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Each individual *usually* signs the document for himself, thus confirming that he's the author or that he authorizes the document. In this case s/he uses own certificate with a private key. It is also possible that several people share the same certificate and a key (eg. several VPs each of them having the right to approve certain document).
2. You can use some Office automation or you can use some third-party library such as our [SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-security.php) (among other features it supports PDF signing, Office document signing and XML signing using format-specific signature standards, and also CMS/CAdES "generic" signing). Samples are included into the downloadable package.

Note that PDF format doesn't support having several independent signatures. Office signature formats do support independent signatures (moreover, in binary formats countersigning is not possible).